# Encontro Stack Overflow v4.5?

Tags: debate, meetup

Como boa parte sabe, nós estamos patrocinando o [DevDay](http://devday.devisland.com), em Belo Horizonte, no dia 31 de Outubro. Eu e a [Roberta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/901/rla4) estaremos lá e ela vai palestrar sobre a arquitetura do Stack Overflow e como nós mantemos o site no ar - exceto quando o CloudFlare decide parar de funcionar.

Eu gostaria de aproveitar a viagem e *talvez* fazer algo em algum outro lugar. Conversar sobre o site, o que vocês estão achando, que problemas vocês veem, o que gostam e o que não gostam. É uma excelente oportunidade de me xingar também, se esse for o caso.
Ou só sentar e jogar conversa fora.

Então a pergunta é:

1. Onde fazer um encontro? Sei que temos muita gente em São Paulo, mas ao mesmo tempo já teve bastante encontro lá. Não seria nada mal dar uma variada.
2. Quando? Independente do dia exato, eu só vou poder entre os dias 01/11 e 13/11. Claro que encontros podem ocorrer sem minha presença, mas eu realmente queria aproveitar a oportunidade de conversar com quem puder aparecer.

O que acham?

## UPDATES

Vou listar os encontros aqui. Se você quiser participar ou tiver uma sugestão, basta editar a pergunta.

### São Paulo, 07/11/2015

- **Local a definir**
  [Aceitando sugestões!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4482/encontro-sopt-s%C3%A3o-paulo)
- **Participantes**  (coloque seu nome na lista)

  - Gabe
  - Cigano
  - Math
  - [Ezequiel Barbosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/27669/ezequiel-barbosa)
  - [Daniel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4816/daniel-gomes)
  - Duds
  - [Guerra](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/36/guerra)
  - [Wellington Avelino](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/10315/wellington-avelino) (Após as 17 horas? :D)
  - [PC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/34848/sambarilove)
  - Jessi

### Santa Catarina, 31/10/2015 (ou algum sábado subsequente. Sugestões?)

- **Local a definir**
  Aceitando sugestões! - (Penso em Floripa, ou Blumenau... moro no meio termo entre os 2)
- **Participantes**  (coloque seu nome na lista)

  - [Fernando =)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2998/fernando)
  - [Bruno César o/](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23885/bruno-c%C3%A9sar)
  - Guilherme Lautert

Comment: Vou fazer greve de SOpt até me pagarem passagem ;)

Comment: Seria uma boa mesmo, mais da minha parte complicou... Estarei em BH somente no dia do evento. Poderíamos marcar de almoçar todos juntos lá, sei lá é uma idéia.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ou organizarmos um outro encontro em Portugal `:D`

Comment: Não acredito que perdi o sorteio do DevDay

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, cara, voce perdeu mesmo, todos que participaram do sorteio ganharam o ingresso... http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4268/devday-2015-belo-horizonte-brasil?cb=1  Fica pra próxima... ;-)

Comment: Se quiser dar uma variada pós-BH, a escolha óbvia sem ser SP seria RJ.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo. Mas preciso saber quem de lá tem disponibilidade, e quando...

Comment: Cariocas e fluminenses (e flamenguistas, e vascaínos): manifestem-se!

Comment: Partiu [All Black](http://www.allblack.com.br/) beber!

Comment: A escolha obvia para variar entre o eixo Rio-São Paulo e Portugal(?), seria **Santa Catarina**! Hehe! =D **#encontroSOptVersaoSC**

Comment: @Fernando que tal dia 06/11?

Comment: @Gabe, não vou a BH, só estou dando ideias para futuros encontros. Pelo que vejo SC tem um bom publico! Vocês estão participando do [TDC](http://www.thedevelopersconference.com.br/) ainda? Mas podemos marcar uma data e local sim! =D. E há algo dia 06/11 por aqui?

Comment: @Fernando foi o que eu disse, que tal dia 06/11 pro encontro em SC?

Comment: @Gabe, só tem um problema para mim, se não tiver um evento ou algo para ir é complicado ser durante a semana! Dia 06/11 é uma Sexta-Feira! Mas podemos abrir um tópico para ver como o restante dos Catarinenses! **#encontroSOptVersaoSC**

Comment: @Fernando edita o post e coloca lá a data (e local, se tiver algo em mente). Eu até posso outro dia antes, mas acho que sexta feira é melhor, né

Comment: @Fernando Valeu!

Comment: @Fernando em SC seria legal, tô em Floripa, mas qualquer lugar num raio de ~200km seria tranquilo :)

Comment: Esse encontro vai ser que horas? tenho um evento na locaWeb ate as 17 horas nesse mesmo dia :(

Answer (score 8):

Podia ser em Lisboa visto que é pt então podia ser na capital :)

Comment: Ou no Porto, cada um puxa a brasa a sua sardinha :P

Comment: Em em NY, assim todos poderiam comprar Playstations baratinho. ;)

Comment: @Amadeu estou em Portugal faz 2 meses. Adoraria conhecer a comunidade.

Answer (score 7):

Consegui a passagem de volta só pro dia 1º. Pro dia 2 estava muito cara. Tem alguma possibilidade de você vir a São Paulo entre os dias 2 e 13?

Em BH poderia ser no dia 31, depois do DevDay.

Comment: Tem. É uma das coisas que eu quero descobrir... Qual vai ser meu itinerário...

Answer (score 7):

Acho que seria uma boa fazer no dia 31, depois do DevDay. Aproveitar que vai ter bastante gente por lá.

Comment: Concordo com você :)

Answer (score 5):

Interessante nem sabia que tinha esse encontro. Eu gostaria de ir mas só poderei se for em SP.

Comment: Vai ter em SP dia 07/11!

Comment: @Gabe onde posso encontrar mais detalhe (local, horário, etc)?

Comment: Olha o update na pergunta

Comment: @Gabe muito bom, o que costuma acontecer nesse encontro, como é?

Comment: Varia... Já teve um com coisas organizadas, já teve um monte em que o pessoal só sentou e bateu papo. Dessa vez vai ser só bater papo.

Comment: Entendi, eu vou cara pode por meu nome na lista.

Comment: Só editar a pergunta e botar seu nome na lista!

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se ia ser uma boa para **todos** os usuários do StackOverflow PT... Pois creio que maioria não iria ter condições de ir visitar o local, como eu por exemplo, queria muito poder conversar com programadores, mas... infelizmente esse é o único problema.

Comment: Como assim "todos os usuários"?

Comment: Nada não, você mudou a pergunta rsrsrs

Comment: Mudei não, hahaha. Acho que você leu alguma coisa errada `:D`

Comment: Bah, esquece haha

Answer (score 4):

Eu gostaria de ir mas só poderei se for em SC.
Irei de carro se alguém quiser acompanhar.
Sou de Novo Hamburgo, RS

Comment: Tem um encontro proposto pra SC. Edita a pergunta e põe seu nome lá!

Answer (score 3):

Acho bacana a ideia de socializar e tals, mas eu apreciaria muito mais algo como palestras sobre temas relacionados a programação (achei bastante interessante [o que o pessoal do SO fez](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/10/Beyond-Coding-Recap-Helping-Emerging-Developers-Launch-Careers/?cb=1)).

Sou uma das muitas pessoas do SO que não é programadora por formação mas sim de coração. Estou aprendendo a gastar mais tempo em aprender boas práticas de programação ao invés de simplesmente resolver problemas.

Percebo que tem muita gente boa aqui. Não sei se daria certo, se haveria voluntários, mas eu iria gostar bastante de ver palestras da galera aqui.

---

Dito isso, a [Ludus](http://www.ludusluderia.com.br/) é um lugar legal em SP.

Prefiro não confirmar minha presença, mas se eu acordar com bons níveis de habilidades sociais no dia eu apareço.

Comment: A gente já tentou realizar encontros mais.. _técnicos_ antes, só que acabou não acontecendo conforme o esperado. Não que isso não possa acontecer um dia, mas no geral reunir todos em volta de uma mesa e jogar conversa fora é muito mais fácil de acontecer. De qualquer forma, tente aparecer lá no dia :)

Comment: Entendi. Devia imaginar que algo simples/bacana assim já devia ter sido pensado/testado/falhado. Sim, tentarei aparecer lá no dia.

Comment: Pode sugerir aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4482/3117

Answer (score 3):

Bora!!!!

Vamos escolher o local!

Comment: [Ludus](http://www.ludusluderia.com.br/)?

Comment: Legal heim @Math, não conheço ainda!
Acho válido!!

Comment: Eu tb não, foi [sugetão da carla](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4420/3117), rs

Comment: hahahaha @carla, boa !

Answer (score 2):

Eu toparia um encontro no **Rio de Janeiro** . Já houve algum encontro ou DevDay por aqui?

Inclusive sou de MG e vou estar por lá este fim de semana, mas não na capital. Perto do local do DevDay, sugeriria algum barzinho no Outro Preto. Caso prefiram em outro bairro, só procurar por Savassi, Sion, Lourdes ou Santa Teresa (numa das últimas vezes que fui a BH fui na Parada do Cardoso, ótima pizza).

Comment: Eu gostaria que houvesse um encontro no RJ, mas nunca ninguém se manifestou