# Encontro SOpt - São Paulo

Tags: debate, meetup

Como discutido no [post sobre o DevDay](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4379), vamos ter um Encontro de Usuários do SOpt em São Paulo, **sábado, dia 07 de novembro**. Naquele post nós definimos uma lista de participantes, mas não o local.

Como o dia do encontro vem chegando, tá na hora de efetivamente organizar um horário e local para todo mundo se encontrar. O encontro é absolutamente informal. Apenas uma chance de vocês se conhecerem, eu conhecer vocês, trocar uma ideia, bater papo, comer e beber.

Eu não conheço São Paulo, então não posso opinar sobre que lugar seria ideal. Espero sugestões dos participantes, para que eu possa fazer a reserva.

Então, onde vai ser?

## UPDATE

**Reservado!**

A reserva foi feita para 15 pessoas no sábado, dia 07 de Novembro às 18h.

A Luderia so garante os lugares até às 20h, então tentem chegar o mais cedo possível.

Vejo vocês lá!

## UPDATE 2

Cheguei!
Temos uma mesa logo na entrada.
Quem chegar, só falar que tem reserva no nome "Gabriel Koscky".

Quanto mais cedo vocês chegarem, mais tempo a gente joga Zumbicídio!

## UPDATE 3

Fotos do Evento: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=oa.793239757488699&type=1

Answer (score 17):

## [Ludus Luderia](http://www.ludusluderia.com.br/)

> A Ludus Luderia é um bar especializado em jogos de tabuleiro, um espaço para beber, comer, conversar e jogar, é claro!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Eu não bebo, então o catalisador de conversas que eu uso são jogos de tabuleiro.

De todo modo, eles servem bebida lá também.

Fica a 750m da Av. Paulista.

---

## Mas jogo de tabuleiro não é coisa de criança?

Nem todos. Na verdade, é uma afirmação tão errada quanto dizer que jogos de videogame, animes/mangá, filmes ou livros são coisas de criança. Existem obras infantis mas existem muitas outras para adultos ou mesmo para ambos.

## Não manjo nada dos jogos, o que eu faço?

Na Ludus há monitores que além de explicar as regras dos jogos, sugerem jogos para quem não faz ideia do que quer.

## Vai ser tipo War/Detetive/etc? Já trabalhei a semana toda e vou ter de pensar no fim-de-semana?

Existem vários tipos de jogos. Variam com o nº de jogadores, tempo de jogo, dificuldade de aprendizado, fator raciocínio vs sorte. Tem para todos os gostos.

---

**#Minhas sugestões**

Talvez não role de eu ir, mas aos que aqui passarem, deixo a Ludus aos seus cuidados: Bang, Munchkin, Tabu, Dix it, Saboteur, The Resistance (não sou muito fã, mas galera curte e é um dos que mais impele as pessoas a conversar), Tesouro Inca.

Comment: Eu voto nessa! Mesmo que bebesse ainda votaria nessa, porque jogo de tabuleiro é o que há!

Comment: Boa tarde Carla! Tem esse tabuleiro lá: http://www.ludusluderia.com.br/image/a-ludus_2.jpg ? Se eu pude-se ir, eu com certeza votaria por este local :D

Comment: @Gabe não sei se gosta da DC ou de Xadrez, mas imagine este tabuleiro na sua mesa http://blogdebrinquedo.com.br/2011/12/13/xadrez-do-batman-iluminado-com-50-leds/ :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Hahahaha me lembrou meu [xadrez do Mario](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91w-uj9SRcL._UL1500_.jpg)

Comment: @Gabe Nossa que massa! Gostaria muito de ver uma versão do SMRPG, pena que Square/Enix e Nintendo não se entendem mais :(

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não sei se tem esse Detetive estilizado aí...de todo modo, pra mim ir na Ludus jogar War/Banco Imobiliário/Detetive,etc. é como ir numa churrascaria e ficar no buffet de saladas; você está desperdiçando todo o potencial do lugar.

Comment: @carla Eita, mas eu não quero pra jogar, é porque os bonecos a principio me pareciam dos anos 30/40/50 (a foto ta embaçada)... E acho legal ter e não jogar necessariamente. Por falar nisto que jogos você tem em mente?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Depende da dificuldade/nºjogadores/duração/sorteVSraciocínio que a galera quiser. Pensei em cada um pegar um cubo mágico e fazermos um torneio. OU, como imagino que a galera prefira jogos de média dificuldade, pra bastante gente, que não demorem muito e que não gaste todo o processamento do cérebro, eu sugiro: Munchkin, Bang, Dix it, Saboteur...

Comment: @carla Infelizmente não posso ir, porque é muito longe pra mim, mas.... sugiro que coloque isto na sua publicação editando ela :) Eu gostei muito da sua sugestão e tenho certeza que outras pessoas irão gostar! É apenas uma dica pra você demonstrar o quanto o lugar é legal, promover a sua sugestão, entende?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Entendi, não sabia que vc gostava tanto de cubos mágicos... Enfim, achei que o fato de colocar uma foto sem ninguém aqui e um lugar lotado no outro seria o suficiente para galera decidir Ludus, mas vejo que não se fazem mais nerds antissociais como antigamente. Chegando em casa vou editar o post então.

Comment: Na verdade não me referia ao cubo mágico, mas a todas sugestões que você tiver de jogos @carla, já que você conhece o lugar e os jogos :) Espero em uma próxima vez poder participar! Se divirtam lá.

Comment: ...o foda de se fazer uma piada na internet é que ou você faz ela bem óbvia (e perde um pouco a graça) colocando um emoticon (p.ex. =P) ou você não coloca nada e só parece que você é burra mesmo....foda. =/ (PS: toda a história dos cubos mágicos era uma piada...[ainda bem que nem fiz minha piada sobre jogar twister pelado então...])

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vc sabe que a SO que vai pagar a conta né? Mesmo assim não dá para vc ir no encontro?

Comment: @Math Sei sim, eu queria muito ir, mas a distancia me impossibilita, o trabalho anda puxado :/ - Vamos ver até lá.

Comment: @carla kkkkk nem digo que foi uma piada de nerd, mas sim de "gamer", com o tempo eu me acostumo com as piadas prometo... No caso o burro sou eu :P

Comment: Será que tem Zombicide? Zombicide é bom demais!

Comment: @Gabe Sim, tem Zombicide. Particularmente, na mesma temática, prefiro Last Night on Earth, mas eles não têm lá. =/

Comment: Eu prefiro esse, até porque eu muito podendo beber, e ir num pub e não beber é o cúmulo.
Só pra complementar, quer horário vai ser o encontro, pra eu já comprar a passagem.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa boa pergunta, ainda não sei o horário, mas para ter uma base o horário de funcionamento aos sábados é das 18h às 03h (do domingo). Tirei essa informação do próprio site deles.

Comment: Nos vemos no Ludus então??

Answer (score 12):

## [All Black Irish Pub](http://www.allblack.com.br/)

> O All Black traz para São Paulo um pouco do modo de vida irlandês.
>
> Um pub com boa bebida, boa comida, boa musica, boa conversa e o mais importante alto astral e bom divertimento.

[image: All Back Irish Pub interno]

---

Foi minha sugestão vez passada. Fica bem localizado, entre Faria Lima e Vila Madalena.

> Rua Oscar Freire - 163, Jardim Paulista

Comment: Deixa de ser bêbado, Cigano! +1

Comment: Mas que comentário mais indecoroso. Vou chamar os moderadores.

Comment: Pra beber junto, claro.

Comment: All Black não fecha aos sábados?

Comment: Não. Eles não seriam doidos.

Comment: @Gabe se mandares um bilhete de avião patrocinado pelo SO eu vou ;)

Comment: cacófato (não pude deixar de notar).

Comment: HAHAHAAHHA @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não desiste do all black! Vamos pro morrison rock bar!, mas eu topo fácil o All black!!!!!!!

Comment: @carla A vespa assada?

Comment: @bfavaretto Exato!! :D

Answer (score 2):

[Morrison Rock Bar](http://www.morrison.com.br/home/#!/home)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> R. Inácio Pereira da Rocha, 362 - Pinheiros, São Paulo - SP, 05432-011

Comment: Parece legal, de detalhes faça a propaganda do local :D

Comment: Pode ser o after!

Comment: Vou fazer uma edição melhor kkkkk