# Encontro SOpt - Curitiba, PR - 06/09/2017

Tags: debate, meetup

O SOpt vai [patrocinar o DevDay 2017](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6216), em Belo Horizonte!

Mas não tem motivo pra restringir a festa a um lugar só! E Curitiba foi, de longe, a [cidade mais votada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6234) para termos um encontro SOpt. Então se preparem para comer, beber, conhecer uns aos outros e bater papo por nossa conta!

Melhor que isso, só *Zelda: Breath of the Wild*<sup>1</sup>.

Eu sei que, naquele post, eu havia dado as datas como o fim de semana entre 08-10 de setembro. Mas de lá pra cá, duas coisas aconteceram:

1. Eu me toquei que há um feriadão, começando no dia 07/09. Independência desse Brasilzão Sem Porteira. E o fim de semana no meio do feriado acaba não sendo muito conveniente, porque muita gente tá viajando ou festejando em algum outro lugar.
2. Quando sugeri aos que tinham votado em Curitiba as possíveis datas para o encontro, a quarta-feira 06/09 foi, de longe, a mais bem votada.

Acho que faz mais sentido. Antes do feriado, então não atrapalha os planos de ninguém, e tá todo mundo animado com os 4 dias de folga pela frente. Parece um bom dia para comer de graça!

Agora **preciso da ajuda de vocês para escolher um local!** Algumas considerações básicas:

- De fácil acesso
- Que comporte um bom número de pessoas. No momento são 12 pessoas votando por um encontro em Curitiba, então essa é uma boa estimativa.
- Que tenha comida e bebidas disponíveis.
- De preferência algo mais interessante que só um bar. Algumas pessoas não bebem, outras não gostam do ambiente e barulho. Quanto mais convidativo o lugar, melhor. Em São Paulo, por exemplo, [fizemos numa ludoteca](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4485). Pensem fora da caixa!

Quando decidirmos um local, eu me encarrego de organizar as coisas (mas não negarei ajuda). Quanto antes conseguirmos um lugar, melhor. Temos apenas um mês até o encontro!

### Então preciso de duas coisas:

1. Votem na minha resposta, confirmando o interesse e disponibilidade de participar
2. Enviem as respostas de vocês com sugestões de local, e votem nas suas preferidas!

Vejo vocês em Curitiba!

tl;dr:

**O que**: Encontro SOpt - Curitiba

**Quando**: 06/09/2017 a partir das 18:00

**Onde**: [Cooldown E-Sports N' Burgers](http://cooldown.com.br)
Av. Silva Jardim, 1145 • Curitiba / PR

**Como**: Vote na minha resposta para confirmar presença (mesmo que sem certeza), e vote nas outras respostas para escolher um local!

---

<sup>1. Recomendo <sup>2</sup></sup>
<sup>2. Eu sei que já falei isso no [post de BH](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6273), mas o jogo é muito bom... merece o repeteco</sup>

Comment: [#eufui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6276/5878)

Answer (score 8):

## Eu posso ir no Encontro SOpt em Curitiba, dia 06/09/2017

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguma notícia? Seremos apenas 7 pessoas mesmo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Estou ajeitando as coisas com a Cooldown para confirmar a reserva. Quanto às pessoas, espero que sejam essas 7, sim. Mas podem levar outra pessoa, se quiserem

Answer (score 8):

## [Cooldown E-Sports N' Burgers](http://cooldown.com.br)

Também não conheço ainda, mas é uma hamburgueria com ambiente integrado a jogos eletrônicos. Por ser uma hamburgueria, acredito que satisfaça os quesitos de bebida e comida, além de um ambiente mais calmo que um bar, sem contar os jogos, que acredito que há um pessoal aqui que curte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não posso votar, afinal a escolha é de vocês... Mas eu certamente não reclamaria de um mini lan-party SOpt!

Comment: CS CS CS CS CS!11

Comment: Posso participar remotamente :)

Comment: Esse lugar é mt massa, vale muito a pena!

Comment: Esse lugar é muito bom!!!

Comment: Depois de ver que eles possuem [mana potion](http://cooldown.com.br/drinks/) até eu tenho vontade de ir, mesmo sendo outro estado...

Answer (score 4):

Não poderei ir desta vez, mas indico como local do encontro:

### [Hard Rock Cafe Curitiba](http://www.hardrock.com/cafes/curitiba/pt/)

Rua Buenos Aires, 50, Batel, Curitiba - PR

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom encontro pra vocês!!!