# Quando é o Próximo encontro stack overflow?

Tags: debate

Algum próximo encontro marcado?

Se sim e Lisboa terá Lugar para esse encontro tambem?
[Encontro Stack Overflow v4.5?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4379/encontro-stack-overflow-v4-5/4392#4392)

Comment: Depender da empresa, provavelmente "nunca". Sinceramente a empresa parece estar mais focada em forçar o helpdesk para ganhar numeros do que na qualidade e apoio aos colaboradores. Se for rolar um encontro será feito por membros somente

Comment: @rla4 você sabe de alguma coisa?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes já houve um em Coimbra. Se quiseres organizar um, é só perguntar aqui no meta e ver o que os portugueses acham disso. Não somos muitos e cada vez menos ativos, mas não custa ver o que acontece.

Comment: Dizem que em Curitiba é bem legal para fazer encontros do SOpt

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes quem frequenta o META.se (vulgo METÃO) está vendo as atitudes da empresa, não quero falar mais do que é devido aqui, porque eventualmente isto pode acarretar algo para mim, mas pode olhar o METÃO e tirar suas conclusões e formar sua propria opinião, que talvez será diferente da minha.

Comment: Se houver algum em Portugal que avisem aqui no meta

Comment: Será que podíamos organizar entre membros ?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes por que não? Gostaria de participar, dependendo do lugar escolhido